simulink model deploy successfully on pi ,run the elf document directly on pi ,but failed
the elf documents has been deployed ,i run it ,but failed.it says "initInitialise: can't lock /var/run/pigpio.pid    ERR_PWM_PIGPIOINIT.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
